Wordpress ACF: show post ID in post object dropdown in admin
I have a two custom post types, Team and Projects.
In the admin section of Projects I can select team members connected to the project from an acf post object, now I would like to show the Post ID of the team member with the post title in the drop down.
I played with acf/render_field/type=post_object but did not find a solution…

Check this on ACF - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-post_object-result/ using acf/fields/post_object/result filter is what you are looking for.

According to the ACF documentation at:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-render_field/
&
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-post_object-result/
// tweak acf post object results to display the title AND the post ID
add_filter( 'acf/fields/post_object/result', 'nitro_post_object_results_title', 10000, 4 );
function nitro_post_object_results_title( $title, $post, $field, $post_id ) {
    
    if ( wp_doing_ajax() ) {
        return $title .' ('.  $post->ID .')';
    }
    return $title;
}

// display selected value below the field
add_action( 'acf/render_field/type=post_object', 'nitro_post_object_render_field', 10, 1 );
function nitro_post_object_render_field( &$field ) {
    
    echo ( !empty( $field['value'] ) ? '<small>Value: '. $field['value'].'</small>' : '' );

}

On the first filter / function we are adding the post ID to the drop down.
On the second /action/ function we are displaying the already selected value.
